# Set-theoretical foundations of Mathematics with only bounded quantifiers

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, mathematical-philosophy

It seems that outside of researchers in Mathematical Logic, mathematicians use almost exclusively bounded quantifiers instead of unbounded quantifiers. In fact, I haven't observed any other practice from the very first day on when I was a student.

For example, a logician would write

$\forall a : ( a \in \mathbb R ) \rightarrow ( a^2 \geq 0 )$

whereas most working analysists and algebraists write

$\forall a \in \mathbb R : a^2 \geq 0$

On the other hand, most mathematicians I know accept the idea that all of mathematics can be built up from set-theoretical foundations alone (starting the natural numbers).

So there seems to be a set of assumptions, almost universally agreed upon, which most working mathematicians assume implicitly for their practice. These assumptions start with set theory but apparently exclude unbounded quantifiers. In fact, unless you attend a class in formal logic you might never encounter unbounded quantifiers.

It seems that most mathematicians use a subset of human language enhanced with a subset of mathematical language (avoiding universal quantifiers) as their working language.

**Question:** Have there been attempts at precisely identifying this mathematical sublanguage and the rules that it governs?

Comment: There is no logical difference between the above two expressions.  Bounded quantification is simply defined as the kind of implication you write.

Comment: There is no logical difference between the above two expressions. Unbounded quantification is simply defined as quantification bounded by the class of all sets $V$.

Comment: I think one keyword for this question might be _predicative_.

Comment: @AndrejBauer you miss the point. (S)he didn’t give an example of true unbounded quantification.

Comment: I just couldn't help myself.

Answer (score 16):

> The most ambitious (and well-argued) attempt at formulating a set-theoretical foundation of the type you are proposing using bounded quantification has been suggested by non other than Saunders Mac Lane in the last chapter of his book [Mathematics, Form and Function](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781461293408).

Mac Lane dubbed his system ZBQC, which can be described as a weakening of [Zermelo set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo_set_theory) in which the scheme of separation is limited to formulae with bounded quantification.  Curiously, at the level of consistency strength, ZBQC is the only known lower bound to the consistency strength of Quine's system [NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Foundations); moreover, it is known that  that the urelement-version, NFU, of NF (in which the axiom of infinity is included) is equiconsistent with ZBQC.

> On the other hand, Adrian Mathias has critically-and-forcefully responded to Mac Lane's thesis to found mathematics on ZBQC; see [here](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~ardm/mathiasmaclane.pdf) for an article of his addressed to philosophers and general mathematicians, together with a response from Mac Lane; and [here](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~ardm/maclane.pdf) for an article addressed to logicians.

Comment: I"m not sure what "(weak) upper bound" means, but I'd understand "ZBQC is an upper bound to the consistency strength of NF" to mean that  Con(ZBQC) implies Con(NF). Did you mean the converse of that?

Comment: @AndreasBlass I will change the wording to make it more clear, I put the parenthetical "weak" to distinguish it from "strict", and as you suspected, "upper bound" should have been "lower bound".

Comment: The conclusion of Randall Holmes’s purported proof of consistency of NF (https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.01406) suggests that it has the consistency strength of ZBQC, so the lower bound may actually be tight.

Comment: If I remember right, there is a good treatment of Mac Lane’s ZBQC in the book by John Bell.

Comment: Does bounded ZFC (i.e. with both separation and replacement limited to bounded formula) prove consistency of ZC (with unbounded separation but no replacement)?

Comment: Oh I suppose the answer is "no" because MOST is equiconsistent with MAC, and MAC is weaker than ZC. Is that right?

Comment: Last two links are broken.

Answer (score 12):

Most mathematics can be done in logical systems which are far weaker than Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory. For example, something like [structural set theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/structural+set+theory) will suffice for a great deal of ordinary mathematics.

It's not exactly true that mathematicians never use unbounded quantification. For example, in category theory [universal properties](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/universal+construction) quantify over all objects of a category. When the category in question is large this amounts to unbounded quantification. In a sense, such quantification is "harmless" because it is "on the outside", i.e., it is of the form $\forall X . \phi(X)$ where $\phi$ itself contains no further unbounded quantifiers. In many cases we can replace such a statement with a *schema* $\phi(X)$ where $X$ is a schematic symbol (that is, instead of having a single formula $\forall X . \phi(X)$ we have many separate formulas $\phi(X)$, one for each $X$).

Occasionally one sees mathematical statements which do contain inner unbounded quantifiers, but those are not common. One example I can think of is the following. The notion of *epimorphism* in a category requires quantification over all objects: a morphism $f : A \to B$ is *epi* when for all all $C$ (unbounded quantifier!) and $g, h : B \to C$, if $g \circ f = h \circ f$ then $g = h$. Often in concrete example we can characterize epis equivalently with some statement that only contains bounded quantifiers (e.g., in the category of sets a map is epi if, and only if it is surjective), but if we make general statements about epis in large categories, large quantification will be required.

Comment: I like your example of quantification over a large category. Nevertheless, do you know of some "hyper-universal property" that requires a quantification over _all_ the universe of discourse of category theory? (I really don't know what this last thing might be, nor whether it could include the category of all categories and the like.)

Comment: @Pedro: Yes; a standard statement like “If a category C has all products and equalisers, then it has all limits.” (Though again the most-unbounded quantifier is on the outside.)

Comment: What about everyday $\Pi_2$ statements like “every field has a closure,” or “every category has a Cayley representation,” or “every vector space has a basis,” etc? Aren’t these ordinary and common mainstream mathematical statements?

Comment: @MonroeEskew: I am not sure I get your point. Those are just more examples of the "easy" unbounded quantifier $\forall$ on the outside, like universal properties in category theory. The inner $\exists$ can easily be made bounded. Can you think of statements where the inner quantifiers cannot be made bounded easily?

Comment: I don’t know what you mean by making the second quantifier bounded. Take the basis example. Where is the basis? Is it in the vector space? No, it is a subset. Furthermore its existence requires a set theoretic assumption.

Comment: @MonroeEskew: If one has a “power set” operation on sets/types/objects (as many fonudational systems do), then a quantification over subsets is still bounded.  Even without that, if one has a “universe” or something that can function as one, then a quantification over bases from that universe can be given as a bounded quantification: e.g. if you have a set/type/object of natural numbers, then quantification over “finite bases” can be given as a bounded quantification.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine But the assertion “$x = P(y)$” is irreducibly $\Pi_1$ in the Levy hierarchy, meaning it needs an unbounded quantifier.  You can kinda cheat, introducing new symbols in the language to make every formula equivalent to a quantifier-free formula in a given structure. But when comparing different structures (i.e. inner models), the fact that you cheated will be revealed, as the non-absoluteness of your higher-complexity formulas will be seen.

Comment: @MonroeEskew: let us not confuse a particular first-order set-theoretic language based on $\in$-relation with mathematical practice. It is quite natural to have a langauge in which the powerset (and other basic set-theoretic operations) are primitive function symbols. So yes, we need to fix a language, but let us fix something that looks like mathematical practice.

Comment: @AndrejBauer I don’t think I’m confusing something, but rather giving a counter example to your reasoning.

Comment: The notion of “harmlessness” you mention in your post can be made precise by talking about absoluteness.

Comment: @Monroe: The point that these examples are $\Pi_1$ is important, but I read it with a very different informal interpretation than you do: I see such examples as illustrating that the informal concept the Lévy hierarchy formalises is *not* really quite “unbounded quantification”, but something more like “higher-order quantification”.  And it’s worth appreciating that ZFC and its choice of language is not the only foundational system; there are systems where products genuinely require unbounded quantification, and systems where power-objects do not.

Comment: (cont’d) As with anything foundational, it’s great to have precise definitions that aim to formalise concepts from informal practice, but one mustn’t make them a Procrustean bed when they don’t quite fit those informal notions.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine: I have to confess that I never received an *informal* concept of (un)bounded quantification.  One has to be clear about what the *bounds* are.  In the usage I’m most familiar with, and what seems to be that of the OP, the bounds are restriction to membership in a given set.  The usefulness of this notion are the various absoluteness theorems about it.  (Of course, in the set-theoretic context, all of these considerations regard first-order logic.)

Comment: (cont’d) As I mentioned, one can always do a model-theoretic “cheat” to eliminate any desired quantifiers in some sense, but the question is whether this results in something interesting.  And the right test for that seems to be comparing truths in different structures of the same language and base theory.  Which is not to say that set theory is the only context in which this is relevant.  In set theory, “$x = y \times z$“ is $\Delta_0$ and thus quite absolute. But perhaps in certain categorical contexts it has a different complexity and is not so absolute.

Comment: I apologize, I've been stuck at home with a fever which seems to be getting the better of me. But please, do try to understand other people's points of view, even if they're not just set theory.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Thank you for your example, but much more for the observation that it is difficult to go beyond "the outer quantifier." Though I'm a set theory fan, I adhere to your point here. .... While I'm writing the following example came to my mind: _Every category has a skeleton_. Do you consider here that a "powerset category" (plus AC) is available to construct this?